# How to use html edit character (&#x270E;) instead of directly use "edit" in cakephp?

Tags: php, html, cakephp-3.0

i have this link

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $o->id]) ?>.
```

Instead of **Edit** ,i want to use edit html character **(✎)**.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add "escape" parameter and set it to false.

You may wanna refer to this: [CakePHP 3 creating links](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links)

```
<?php 
     echo Html->link(__('&#x270E;'), 
         ['action' => 'edit', $o->id],
         ['escape' => false]
 ) ?>
```

Comment: But for this post link not work this  .  <?=  $this->Form->postLink('&#x274E;', ['action' => 'delete', $o->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $o->id)],['escape' => false]); ?>

Comment: You've declared two different arrays for confirm and escape. Please place "confirm" and "escape" within the same array.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
&#x270E;
```

instead of Edit text

will produce ✎ icon